# Linux Dev VM Server - SSH Withouth Authentication

Tags: linux, ssh, authentication

I have a local Linux VM (ubuntu 14.04 LTS) that I use for development. How can I configure ssh to login without any authentication? Again, it's a local dev VM so there are NO security concerns.

Thanks

Comment: Do you truly mean "no authentication" or would no prompting be acceptable? Because for the latter case, I would use ssh keys.

Answer (score 0):

> without any authentication

is not possible in SSH. But there are several alternatives:

- You can set up empty password and allow using empty passwords in `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` and PAM configuration (not recommended)
- You can set up public key authentication using non-encrypted private key:

  ```
  ssh-keygen -t rsa -f ~/.ssh/id_rsa -N ""
  ssh-copy-id your-server
  ```

  And then you will be able to connect "without explicit authentication" (your client will be authorized to access this machine). (recommended)
- You can modify the `openssh` to accept any authentication (or the `none` authentication method, which is against the SSH specification), but I would say it is not worth the effort.